# SSD Not Detected - Fallback on EFI Shell

Tags: hard-drive, boot, ssd, fdisk

Want to assess what are the odds of a hardware failure in a particular case.

I have a laptop with an Intel SSD (160GB). I just installed Windows 8.1 on it and all was working fine, up until the point where the OS froze. I did a hard reset and noticed that I am now booted into the EFI shell.

In the EFI shell, I see that there is a block device, and I can see the block device in the BIOS, however if I try to boot, it always fails, and if I try to reinstall Windows, the install wizard identifies the disk as `size: 0MB`.

I managed to boot into a Linux shell from a USB drive, and `fdisk` reports it as a 32KB, 0-cylinder device.

Which leads me to the question - is the SSD dead or is there something wrong with the partition table that somehow got dropped? Is there anything I can do to diagnose it or bring it back to life?

Comment: You can attempt to do file recovery on it, however, if you wrote any new data to it then that will be unlikely.  That won't fix your problem, the device either failed entirely or simply lost its partition information.  Both are just as likely unless more information about the health of the device can be provided.

Comment: Worth mentioning that I don't care about the data on the disk - it had nothing important on it. To me the piece of hardware is what counts.

Comment: @Ramhound: If it had just lost partition information it wouldn't show up as a 0MB *device*.

Comment: @DenDelimarsky - Why did you ask about data recovery.  I will have to trust Billy on his word, I recall the 8MB bug, so his explanation makes logical sense

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When Intel drives have any kind of problem "booting up" (they really run embedded operating systems) they go into this "look like a very tiny disk" mode. (At least it's better than some other SSDs which just turn into bricks) If you can install the drive in another machine temporarily you may be able to connect Intel's SSD Toolbox software to it to get a better idea of what's going on. This is similar to the "[Intel 8MB Bug](http://www.anandtech.com/show/4625/intel-testing-firmware-fix-for-ssd-320-8mb-power-bug)" from a few years ago.

Otherwise the drive just may be toast :( Good luck!